# php preg_match regex - match chars from a to z and should contain @ char

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

good evening,

i need to check if the input match my regex or not 

i use this pattern `'@^[a-zA-Z\@]{3,30}$@is'`

```
<?php
if( preg_match('@^[a-zA-Z\@]{3,30}$@is', 'input@input') ){ echo 'matched'; }else{ echo 'no match'; }
?>
```

if i removed the `@` char the regex still return `TRUE`

```
<?php
if( preg_match('@^[a-zA-Z\@]{3,30}$@is', 'inputinput') ){ echo 'matched'; }else{ echo 'no match'; }
?>
```

i need to edit the regex so it should contain the `@` char

Comment: so you need how many @s in the string? where in the string does it have to be?

Comment: Please give some example input cases, and whether they are valid or not.

Comment: hi all, what about use @ char at first or at end ? --- true cases: aa@aa , @aa , aa@ --- false cases: aa ..

Comment: thank you all, you all are great ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a look-ahead assertion to assert that:

```
/^(?=[^@]*@)[a-zA-Z@]{3,30}$/is
```

Here the look-ahead assertion `(?=[^@]*@)` ensures that there is at least one `@`.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple - just use `strpos()` to find `@` character in string. For example

```
if(strpos('@','thestring')!==FALSE)
{
  /* it contains @ */
}
else
{
  /* it doesn't */
}
```

Comment: hi GlitchMr, so you need me to use it beside regex ? is there a way to done it by regex only ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
%^[a-z]{2,29}@[a-z@]{2,29}$%is
```

Several Issues I also fixed:

- You don't need to use `[a-zA-Z]` if you specified the `i` controller for case insensitivity.
- You can change the delimiters to whatever (almost) character you'd like, if you know a character will be in the regex pattern, don't use it as delmiter.

Comment: The problem is that `aa@aa` doesn't fit this regexp.

Comment: hi Rikudo Sennin, your note is very important to me . thank you .. * your regex return false .

Comment: Now this regexp is too liberal. It can be above 30 characters and still pass. Sadly, unsolvable without making insane long regexp or another piece of code, like my `strpos()`.

Comment: Unless the OP will state exactly what the terms of a valid string is, I don't see this question getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
~^[a-z]?@[a-z@]+$~i
```

If you need only 1 `@` char between a-z blocks you may use

```
~^[a-z]+@[a-z]+$~i
```

if you want to check full length of string you may use `strlen`, if you want do it for every part separately just replace `+` by `{mincnt,maxcnt}`

Comment: thank you very much RiaD, what about use @ char at first or at end ?

Comment: @al-dr please edit your question to include valid and invalid input examples. We won't guess what you need.